# php codeigniter: Call to undefined method CI_Loader::model()

Tags: php, codeigniter, model

I wanted to make a webapplication using codeigniter but it is a while since I've used it and I'm getting an error whenever I try to load a model in my controller. I'm probably doing something stupid wrong but I can't figure out what it is. So please help me out if u can.

This is the error I get:

[image: error]

Here is the code of my model:

```
<?php 

class post_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function getAllPosts() {
        $this->db->order_by('date', 'desc');
        $query = $this->db->get('post');
        return $query->result();
    }
}
?>
```

Here is the code of my controller where I load the model:

```
<?php 

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Post extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model('post_model');
    }

    public function index() {
        $data['title'] = 'Berichten';
        $data['posts'] = $this->post_model->getAllPosts();

        $this->template->load('posts', $data);
    }
}
```

Autoload:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'form', 'date');
$autoload['model'] = array();
```

**Solved:** I couldn't solve it but I made a new project and copy-pasted my code and now it works just fine, so no idea what was wrong.

Comment: Seems weird to me, almost everything is right, except the `post_model` which should be capitalize at the first letter.

Comment: There's nothing wrong in there. Can you post your `autoload.php` especially the `$autoload['helper']` & `$autoload['model']`?

Comment: @dqlopez I added the autoload. Is there supposed to be something in the $autoload['model'] or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All classes should be uppercase at the first letter

```
class Post_model extends CI_Model {
```

This throws the error when loading the model at line 11

Comment: I'm not sure about this, as noted in the above comment. because the OP gets `Call to undefined method` error.

Comment: OK, have the OP checked if the Welcome controller works?

Comment: OK, then you learned wrong. However, does your Welcome controller run? (" Class names must have the first letter capitalized with the rest of the name lowercase.") http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html

Comment: Seem weird. Are you sure your `system/core/Loader.php` file is there? Google for "call to undefined method ci_loader::model()" shows this error is VERY unusual.

Comment: @jtheman yes the file is there. I don't understand what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
class post_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();//加上这句
    }

    function getAllPosts() {
        $this->db->order_by('date', 'desc');
        $query = $this->db->get('post');
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your model file extension `.html`... change your file extention `.php`...
correct: `model_file.php`
incorrect: `model_file.html`

Check your file format.

Answer (score 0):

Class name must be start with the capital letter and the file name must have the same name of that class with the extension .php
Also remove the closing php tag from the model.The codeigniter class files doesn't need any close tag.It will closes automatically by the framework.