# Call to undefined method CI_Loader::load()

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am following an CodeIgniter tutorial but when i try to load

```
$this->load($subview);
```

I got the error: Call to undefined method CI_Loader::load()

Here is the code for the subview:

```
public function login() {
    $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/user/login';
    $this->load->view('admin/_layout_modal', $this->data);
}
```

Anyone know how to fix this ?

Comment: Blind shot: `$this->load->view($subview)` instead?

Comment: unfortunately not :(
Thnx for the help anyways :_)

Comment: Does your controller extend CI_Controller?

Comment: Yes it does

    class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller

Answer (score 0):

This could be a naming problem.
All Classes in CI should be starting with a capital letter, but your view seems to start with an underscore.

See here:
[php codeigniter: Call to undefined method CI_Loader::model()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21651961/php-codeigniter-call-to-undefined-method-ci-loadermodel)